# array being pushed data but empty when logging

Tags: javascript

Hey all I currently have the forEach method below in an array

```
let distances = []

            markers.forEach((el) => {
              new google.maps.DirectionsService().route({
                origin: address,
                destination: el.address,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
              })
                .then((response) => {
                  distances.push(response) 
                  // For each route, display summary information.
                })
                .catch((e) => console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status))

              console.log(distances)
            })
```

does anyone know why I cant see the items after they are all pushed ?

Comment: Why do you believe anything was actually pushed?

Comment: Your `console.log` is outside the promise.

Comment: console.log inside the then block might give you a better result

Comment: i highly recommend you to study what is [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) first, then you will know whats wrong with your code